# JQuery InArray not working Properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist

Need to find whether array object If exist in array. I have one arrayObject and array collections.

my code:

```
var array = [
{
    id:0,
    item_fields:{text: "stack", type: "2", options: null},
    item_id:"540551c1-1744-4f09-920f-75350ba23cb6",
    item_parent:"e50b00d5-8c3e-449e-92ba-41ff9d46babe",
    sequence:-1
},

{
    id:0,
    item_field_type:"multiChoiceNumeric",
    item_fields:{text: "overflow", type: "RangeNumeric", options: null},
    item_id:"1bacc69f-d8c9-4107-af60-295f8994d249",
    item_parent:"e50b00d5-8c3e-449e-92ba-41ff9d46babe",
    sequence:-1
}];

var arrObj = 
{
    id:0,
    item_field_type:"multiChoiceNumeric",
    item_fields:{text: "stack", type: "2", options: null},
    item_id:"540551c1",
    item_parent:"e50b00d5",
    sequence:-1
}
```

This query returns false:

```
array.some(function(element){return element == arrObj})
```

This query returns -1 (If not found):

```
jQuery.inArray(arrObj,array)
```

Why do both queries return not found results? What should I do to get a correct result?

Comment: `arrObj` is a completely different object than any of the objects in the list.  `inArray`, unless you give it a customer matcher, will match on the object, if it is not a basic type (string, number, etc).  Since they are different objects, they are not the same, and it does not exist in the array.

Comment: Also without further information on what "equality" means in this case, it's hard to write a matcher, as the item_fields, item_id, and item_parent are different

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, variable assignment to Object is similar to a pointer in C; the variable is a reference to the memory location of the Object, not the Object and its contents itself.

```
var x = {};
var y = {};
x === y;
// false
```

Rather than compare equality of references to objects, you can update the callback in `array.some()` to check for deep equality, but this can get cumbersome.

It may be better to compare a key in the objects that you know will be unique, such as `"item_id"`:

```
array.some(function(element) {
  return element.item_id === arrObj.item_id;
});
```

Comment: @Gokul, also in your case `array.some(function(element){return element.item_fields.text== arrObj.item_fields.text})` this would return `true`